# Back button not appearing in UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` inside my entry-point `UIViewController` (VC_A). I have another `UIViewController` (VC_B) that has details for each entry in the `UITableView`. I have a Show segue from VC_A to VC_B that's triggered in code when a `UITableViewCell` is pressed:

```
var passedCellData: CellData!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("it worked!")
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
    passedCellData = currentCell.data
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("OpenDetailSegue", sender: self as UIViewController)
}
```

(Note that `CustomCell` extends `UITableViewCell` and `passedCellData` is a global variable.)

My custom view controller for VC_B has a `data` field, so I popular that in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "OpenDetailSegue") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailController
        svc.data = passedCellData
    }
}
```

`DetailController` is the `UIViewController` for VC_B.

I don't have a `UINavigationController` set up in Storyboard or anything, and both `UIViewController` instances have `UINavigationBar` instances at the top (to set the title). However, there's no Back button in VC_B; its navbar only shows the title (and so once I tap for details, I can't go back).

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think the Back button only appear automatic if you use UINavigationController. In your case, I think you should add a Back button on UINavigationBar of VC_B and write code for Back button TouchUp Inside event.

Comment: How you are adding navigation bar to your view controller ?

Comment: Using Storyboard. I just drag and drop it to the top of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: @rohan You do not have a `UINavigationController`, so I think the `DetailController` is shown as Modal. Add a back button, and executes `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`.

Comment: @Bannings thank you so much! That worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drag and drop your `UINavigationBar` then you can drag and drop `UIBarButtonItem` into your `UINavigationBar` then you can create an action for it like shown below:

```
@IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //dismiss your viewController 
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to add the custom back button.

Put the below line in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
```

Now, mention the selector:

```
func goBack(){
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I put this in the code for VC_B, and still nothing. Do I have to delete the `UINavigationBar` in VC_B?

Comment: @rohan Bro for that you need "back.png" image inside your project. Download and insert inside your project : http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Arrows-Back-icon.png